# Structure assignment in Go is it data race?

Tags: multithreading, go, data-race

I read [this](https://dave.cheney.net/2014/06/27/ice-cream-makers-and-data-races) post about data races. And I understand, that access to interface variable need to be sync. But what about access to struct?

For example we have this code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type s struct {
    field0 uint8
    field1 uint16
}

func main() {
    s0 := s{
        field0: 1,
        field1: 2,
    }
    s1 := s{
        field0: 3,
        field1: 4,
    }

    var shared s
    var loop0, loop1 func()

    loop0 = func() {
        shared = s0
        go loop1()
    }

    loop1 = func() {
        shared = s1
        go loop0()
    }

    go loop0()

    for {
        fmt.Println(shared)
    }
}
```

I build this code with `-race` flag and race detector no detect any errors.
But if `shared` is not a pointer, what really happened? We need set 2 fields (if on stack).

Questions:

1. is it data race?
2. if no, why?

UPD: start loop0

Comment: There's no data race because while you've defined `loop0` and `loop1`, *you never call them*. There is nothing running concurrently in your code, therefore no possibility of a race.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. is it data race?

Yes. Your `loop1` and `loop2` won't race with each other, but they both will race with your `for { fmt.Println() }` loop, because `fmt.Println` reads at the same time the other functions are writing to the same value.

Comment: If you run it enough times, the race detector probably will catch it.  loop0 and loop1 won't race with each other because they never set the value simultaneously.